# Perf collection on kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, permissions, mmap, perf, flamegraph

I am trying to find performance bottlenecks by using the perf tool on a kubernetes pod. I have already set the following on the instance hosting the pod:

```
"kernel.kptr_restrict" = "0"
"kernel.perf_event_paranoid" = "0"
```

However, I have to problems.

1. When I collect samples through `perf record -a -F 99 -g -p <PID> --call-graph dwarf` and feed it to speedscore or similarly to a flamegraph, I still see question marks `???` and the process that I would like to see its CPU usage breakdown (C++ based), the aforementioned `???` is on the top of the stack and system calls fall below it. The main process is the one that has `???` around on it.
2. I tried running `perf top` and it says

`Failed to mmap with 1 (Operation not permitted)`

My questions are:

1. For collecting perf top, what permissions do I need to change on the host instance of the pod?
2. Which other settings do I need to change at the instance level so I don't see any more `???` showing up on perf's output. I would like to see the function call stack of the process, not just the system calls. See the following stack:

[image]

The host OS is ubuntu.

Zooming in on the first system call, you would see this, but this only gives me a fraction of the CPU time spent and only the system calls.

### [image]

UPDATE:

I was able to run `perf top`, by setting
`"kernel.perf_event_paranoid" = "-1"`. However, as seen in the image below, the process I'm trying to profile (I've blackened out the name to hide the name), is not showing me function names but just addresses. I try running them through addr2line, but it says `addr2line: 'a.out': No such file`.

How can I get the addresses resolve to function names on the pod? Is it even possible?

[image]

I was also able to fix the memory-function mapping with perf top. This was due to the fact that I was trying to run perf from a different container than where the process was running (same pod, different container). There may be a way to add extra information, but just moving the perf to the container running the process fixed it.